# XDocument - Iterating Over XML Elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Given an example XML file as such:

```
<libraries>

  <library name="some library">
    <book name="my book"/>
    <book name="your book"/>
  </library>

  <library name="another library">
    <book name="his book"/>
    <book name="her book"/>
  </library>

</libraries>
```

How would one iterate through each library and get only its children? E.g. if I was in the first library element and I went to retrieve all its descendants/children, it would only return with the two books inside it.

I've tried iterating and using XElement.Elements("book"), XElement.Elements(), XElement.Descendants(), etc. but all return every element that is a book (so it would pull the elements from the second library, too). Mostly I think I'm just struggling with understanding how XDocument keeps track of its elements and what's considered a descendant/child.

If possible, if one could explain as to how this would be done with XDocument for an element at any level it'd be appreciated (e.g. if each book had child elements, and if those elements had child elements, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over your XML by going through all the descendents of libraries in the following way.

```
  XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(XmlPath);
  foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("library"))
  IEnumerable<XNode> nodes = item.DescendantNodes();//Here you got book nodes within a library
```

Comment: Turns out that this is what I was trying except in my sleepy state last night, I had typo'd and was doing IEnumerable<XNode> nodes = doc.DescendantNodes() vs item.DescendantNodes(); this is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sheer,

The problem is you are pulling all elements with "book".

If you want to get only items dependant on the parent element, you will have to supply a proper condition.

```
 var v = from n in doc.Descendants("library")
                where n.Attribute("name").Value == "some library"
                select n.DescendantNodes();
```

Now, this will give you element who's name is "some library".